# Polymer in node-webkit: how to render/refresh data changes? Platform.flush() doesn't works

Tags: javascript, node.js, polymer, chromium, node-webkit

I'm implementing a Polymer app in a node-webkit window (v0.11.2, based of node v0.11.13 and chromium 38.0.2125.104).

The app must upload files (to a node.js server) and show the uploading progress in a "paper-progress" component. I've put the progress value in a property to update the paper-progress component.

The uploading process is done by a nodejs class (in the example below: "uploader" var) that calls an event "refresh" for each data chunk uploaded.

The problem is that the browser (chromium in node-webkit) render the paper-progress values very slow (in my computer less than 1 time/sec). If I execute any action within the browser, it updates the component faster. For instance: it is very fast to update the component value if I move the mouse inside the window, and it is less fast if I add an console.log.

Platform.flush() doesn't works to render/update the new value in the component. It seems like the browser refresh himself when there are some free resources available to him (in my computer it refresh every 1 second). I want a smooth motion so I must to tell the component to refresh himself somehow.

The code below is the simplified version of my code:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="uploader">
<template>
  ...
  <paper-progress value="{{progress}}"></paper-progress>
  ...
<template>
<script>
Polymer('my-element', {
  progress: 0,
  uploaderChanged: function(oldValue, newValue) {
    if (typeof newValue !== 'undefined' && newValue) {
      var me = this;
      me.uploader.eventEmitter.on('refresh', function(e) {
        me.progress = calculateFrom(me.uploader.progressFrom);
        // paper-progress doesn't update his value faster enough
        // and Platform.flush() doesn't works to refresh the component:
        Platform.flush();
        // but it will update if I add for instance:
        console.log('progress='+me.progress);
        // or, if I move the mouse inside the node-webkit window,
        // it will update more faster
      });
    }
  },
  calculateProgressFrom: function(...) {...}
});
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Do you have you any idea about?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution: in polymer domcumentation api ( https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#asyncmethod ) there is:

> To do work after changes have been processed, Polymer provides async(). It’s similar to window.setTimeout(), but it automatically binds this to the correct value and is timed to requestAnimationFrame

I moved the progress value update in an async function and it works:

```
<polymer-element name="my-element" attributes="uploader">
<template>
  ...
  <paper-progress value="{{progress}}"></paper-progress>
  ...
<template>
<script>
Polymer('my-element', {
  progress: 0,
  uploaderChanged: function(oldValue, newValue) {
    if (typeof newValue !== 'undefined' && newValue) {
      var me = this;
      me.uploader.eventEmitter.on('refresh', function(e) {
        me.async(me.updateProgress);
      });
    }
  },
  updateProgress: function() {
    this.progress = calculateFrom(this.uploader.progressFrom);
  },
  calculateProgressFrom: function(...) {...}
});
</script>
</polymer-element>
```

Probably it works because async uses requestAnimationFrame.